# Ruby on Rails rake db:drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a command to drop a specific table in the database and not all of them?

Or a way to update a database table

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Ruby on Rails Migration Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).  For example, to drop a table in a migration:

```
class DropProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    drop_table :products
  end

  def self.down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using migration with following command:-

```
def self.up    
  drop_table :table_name   
end
```